# React Native save base64 image to Album

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Third Party API return a "QR code image" in base64 encode,
I need save that image to User's Album.

- CamerRoll - not support saving base64 image to album
- React-Native-Fetch-Blob -
  https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob
  still looking into it
- React-Native-fs - 
  https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs
  I am trying this now
- There are few npm modules with very little Github star (<10)

the React-Native-Fetch-Blob maintainer gone missing, so no one answering Github Issue,
`createFile` from [React-Native-Fetch-Blob Document](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#createfilepath-data-encodingpromise) not working as expected(not saving image into album)

```
  import fetch_blob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';

  // json.qr variable are return from API

  const fs = fetch_blob.fs
  const base64 = fetch_blob.base64
  const dirs = fetch_blob.fs.dirs

  const file_path = dirs.DCIMDir + "/some.jpg"
  const base64_img = base64.encode(json.qr)

  fs.createFile(file_path, base64_img, 'base64')
  .then((rep) => { 
    alert(JSON.stringify(rep));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

## Anyone deal with this problem before?

## How to save a base64 encode Image string to User album? (as a jpg or png file)

because I `fetch` an API with no CORS header,
I can't debug it in `Debug JS Remotely`
Chrome would stop that request from happening,

I have to run that on my Android Phone to make it work
(no CORS control on real phone)

I am planing use Clipboard save base64 string,
and hardcode it in my code,
to debug what's wrong with `react-native-fetch-blob` `createFile` API

Comment: btw, just a simple update: I give up React Native. I built 2 app with RN 0.46 and RN 0.52. For simple app it's fine. but if it's serious Startup App. you raise money and hire people and expect it keep improving. don't use RN. reason: write interface is easy. yes. but problem is third party lib and debugging. you gonna waste a lot of time on these 2

Comment: I remember in 2017 RN is 0.52 or something like that. now it's 2019-4-29. newest version is 0.59. I think RN gonna died out slowly. Don't get me wrong. I admire people who willing to try. but unfortunately RN fail

Comment: Flutter is hot these day(2019) but because I don't need to develop App right now. so I didn't try. I hope they can success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now use only react native fetch blob to achieve this.

Simply replace RNFS.writeFile with

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(file_path, image_data, 'base64')
```

If you wish to view file in native OS viewer you can simply put

```
                if (isAndroid) {
                  RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(file_path, 'application/pdf');
                } else {
                  RNFetchBlob.ios.previewDocument(file_path);
                }
```

Comment: ```RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(file_path, image_data, 'base64')
```  returns a 4digit number for me as a response

Comment: At this time rn-fetch-blob has been abandoned. See github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob. I am not able to even build with it using haul. Perhaps it works better with metro.

Answer (score 29):

Remove `data:image/png;base64,` in your base64 string

```
var Base64Code = base64Image.split("data:image/png;base64,"); //base64Image is my image base64 string

const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;

var path = dirs.DCIMDir + "/image.png";

RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, Base64Code[1], 'base64')
.then((res) => {console.log("File : ", res)});
```

And then I solved my problem.

Comment: You saved my day. Whole time I was writing file along with 'data:image/png;base64' string. And your answer just save me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank so much! You save my day!

Answer (score 8):

I solve the problem,
turn out I forgot `data:image/png;base64,` at beginning of the string.
[image]

I remove it with following code

```
  // json.qr is base64 string
  var image_data = json.qr.split('data:image/png;base64,');
  image_data = image_data[1];
```

and then save the image file

```
  import fetch_blob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
  import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

  const fs = fetch_blob.fs
  const dirs = fetch_blob.fs.dirs      
  const file_path = dirs.DCIMDir + "/bigjpg.png"

  // json.qr is base64 string "data:image/png;base64,..."

  var image_data = json.qr.split('data:image/png;base64,');
  image_data = image_data[1];

  RNFS.writeFile(file_path, image_data, 'base64')
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

## I wrote a blog about this

http://1c7.me/react-native-save-base64-image-to-album/

Answer (score 1):

```js
const path = `${RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath}/My Album`;
await RNFS.mkdir(path);
return await fetch(uri)
   .then(res => res.blob())
   .then(image => {
      RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uri, "base64").then(data => {
         RNFS.appendFile(`${path}/${image.data.name}`, data, "base64").catch(
            err => {
               console.log("error writing to android storage :", err);
            }
         );
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this worked in following example

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions';

 takeSnapshot = async () => {
    const currentStatus = await Permissions.check('storage');

    if (currentStatus !== 'authorized') {
      const status = await Permissions.request('storage');

      if (status !== 'authorized') {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // put here your base64
    const base64 = '';

    const path = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir}/test11.png`;

    try {
      const data = await RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, base64, 'base64');
      console.log(data, 'data');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

Comment: plz help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213519/i-want-to-show-my-image-in-gallery-folder-in-react-native

Comment: At this time rn-fetch-blob has been abandoned. See https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob.  I am not able to even build with it using haul.  Perhaps it works better with metro.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

I was wanna download base64 as an image in **react native**

***this.state.base64img*** is my base64 **without**  'data:image/png;base64,'

```
checkPermision = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      this.downloadImage();
    } else {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
          {
            title: 'Storage Permission Required',
            message: 'App needs access to your storage to download photos',
          },
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('Storage permission Granted');
          this.downloadImage();
        } else {
          console.log('Storage permission not Granted');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('errro', error);
      }
    }
  };

   downloadImage() {
    let date = new Date();
    const { fs} = RNFetchBlob;
    const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
    let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir;

    var path =  PictureDir + '/image_' +
    Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2) +
    '.png';
    console.log("path :-",path,"dirs :-",dirs)


    RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, this.state.base64img, 'base64').then(res => {
      console.log('File : ', res);
      alert('Image downloaded successfully.');
    }).catch((error) => {
         alert(JSON.stringify(error));
       });

  }
```