# Is there a way i can download an image with text appended on it with react native

Tags: image, download, blob, react-native

Im building a react-native app and the screen so far loads an image from a uri into a BackgroundImage and there is also some text loading on top of the image, please see the attached image: [image]

So what i want is to  get this image and text downloaded to the device, merge them if you will?

Any suggestions are welcome..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the ViewShot component from [here](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot).

Here's an example of how you would be able to integrate it with your project (keep in mind this uses the ES6 arrow function syntax):

```
class CaptureImage extends Component {
  capturePic = () => {
    this.refs.viewShot.capture().then(uri => {
      console.log("Path to the image: ", uri);  // do what you want with the url
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        <ViewShot ref="viewShot">

          // your background image components go here (the image with the text you want to capture)

        </ViewShot>

        // rest of your code goes here

        <Button onClick= {() => capturePic()} />  // button just for demonstration purpose
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope you understood :)

Comment: This looks perfect for what i need, ill let you know how i get on , thanks

Comment: Glad to know it's what you need!

Comment: That's almost working, im able to get the base64 string on the image but is there a way to convert it to a blob and download it to the device?

Comment: To save the base64 string as image see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134397/react-native-save-base64-image-to-album) reference. It seems to answer your question.

Comment: Did this answer you question?

Comment: not really , i have a function that downloads the imageurl from the api and that works perfect, the reference i get from the viewshot is this 
 "file:///data/user/0/com.quoteapp/cache/ReactNative-snapshot-image7939597279417791785.jpg" , thn i get the error that i can only download http or https

Comment: According to the reference, the image is already in your phone files. Go to internal storage > android > data > com.quoteapp > cache > image. The image should be there already locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215253/discussion-between-peter-snee-and-sahith02).