# React native how to save image picked from image-picker package

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

Hi everyone I'm trying to make an app like an album.

Simply 2 options, ***Open camera, Pick from library***. I can capture and pick from library ( i will show it on code).

So the problem is I want to save captured or selected image in created custom folder like *('./myAlbumPhotos')*. How can I make it. This showed iamges is only cached images

installed libraries

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

export default class App extends Component {
  
  render() {
    const takePhotoFromCamera = () => {
      ImagePicker.openCamera({
        compressImageMaxWidth: 300,
        compressImageMaxHeight: 300,
        cropping: true,
        compressImageQuality: 0.7,
        saveToPhotos :true
      }).then(image => {
        console.log(image);
        setImage(image.path);
        this.bs.current.snapTo(1);
      });
    }
  
    const choosePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
      ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        cropping: true,
        compressImageQuality: 0.7
      }).then(image => {
        console.log(image);
        setImage(image.path);
        this.bs.current.snapTo(1);
      });
    }
    return (
      <View >
 
      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
        <Text >Take Photo</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
        <Text >Choose From Library</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        
        onPress={() => this.bs.current.snapTo(1)}>
        <Text >Cancel</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    )
  }
}
```

It logs like this
[image]

**I checked it really save photos. The question is how can I give save path. With files system ? . Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same requirement with the same library that you have mentioned. Then the thing that I did was kind of a hack, but it was enough for me. So, this is just a suggestion!

1. Make your takePhotoFromCamera like this.

```js
ImagePicker.openCamera({
    // It converts iOS live photo into jpg
    forceJpg: true,
    // I mean don't remove your old configs. Add this prop as well there
})
```

2. After that, in the "then" callback scope of that openCamera method, do necessaries to save your image like this [React Native save base64 image to Album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134397/react-native-save-base64-image-to-album)